# Requests for reopening in meta an encourageable act?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

If I asked a question in [our main site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) and someone closes my question. If I believe that the both questions are different.

Then is it an encourageable act to present my discussion in [our meta site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/) and ask users to reopen my question?

Comment: yes, it is encourageable to post a question or simply clarify with others on the chatroom.

Comment: Some people have done that in the past .. I personally don't like it. To come to Meta everytime a question is closed. There is a procedure for reopening question. We should take resort to it first.